# CodeNameOne Build Submit Error for First Android App

Tags: codenameone

I just tried to Create a new project of Demo type (Kitchen Sink) and tried to Submit it (Android Build) to Server, But it is giving be the below Socket error.

I have not even changed anything in the project; it's the original Demo app.

- Jar is also built in local folder
- I have signed into my account from eclipse/codenameone properties.
- I have Basic Subscription
- My Network connection is also fine, and there is no proxy being used.
- No entries are seen in the CodeNameOne->Builds tab

**Here is the output from my Eclipse Console**

```
Buildfile: F:/Setups/Eclipse/workspaceLatest/TestCodeNameOne\build.xml

copy-android-override:

copy-libs:

jar:
     [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
     [echo]             code size and wider device support
     [copy] Copying 7 files to F:\Setups\Eclipse\workspaceLatest\TestCodeNameOne\build\tmp
    [javac] F:\Setups\Eclipse\workspaceLatest\TestCodeNameOne\build.xml:147: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 19 source files to F:\Setups\Eclipse\workspaceLatest\TestCodeNameOne\build\tmp
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 3 warnings
    [jar] Building jar: F:\Setups\Eclipse\workspaceLatest\TestCodeNameOne\dist\TestCodeNameOne.jar
    [javac] F:\Setups\Eclipse\workspaceLatest\TestCodeNameOne\build.xml:171: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
```

clean-override:

```
    build-for-android-device:

    [codeNameOne] You sent an android build without submitting a keystore. Notice that you will receive a build that is inappropriate for distribution (although it could be used for debugging purposes). For further details read http://www.codenameone.com/signing.html
    [codeNameOne] Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
    [codeNameOne] Sending build to account: myemailid@izealiant.com
    [codeNameOne] java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    [codeNameOne]   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    [codeNameOne]   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:366)
    [codeNameOne]   at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:43    [codeNameOne]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [codeNameOne]   at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:371)
    [codeNameOne]   at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:473)
    [codeNameOne]   at codenameoneplugin.actions.SendBuild$1.run(SendBuild.java:47)
    [codeNameOne]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    BUILD FAILED
    F:\Setups\Eclipse\workspaceLatest\TestCodeNameOne\build.xml:469: Error in server build process

    Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds
```

**IDE and OS Details**

```
IDE: Eclipse
Desktop OS: Windows 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The build is failing to connect to the amazon servers to perform the build, make sure that you have a proper/stable internet connection.

If you are behind a firewall or proxy make sure to define it in the [simulator networking menu](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/unskin-proxy-support.html) when running the app.